# Deduplication efficiency with TrueCrypt File container and crashplan

Tags: encryption, truecrypt, deduplication, crashplan

I have a 100GB truecrypt container file (among lots of other things) that I am backing up with crashplan onto an external HDD. I have disabled "Preserve modification timestamp of file containers" so that crashplan knows when it has been modified.

However, due to the encryption of the container, will crashplan pretty much have to rebackup the entire container every time I add a file to it? Or does the majority of the container remain exactly the same? I would have thought that due to heavy encryption that most of the container would be altered by simply adding or removing a file. Is that not the case?

Answer (score 1):

If that were the case, adding or moving a file on a TrueCrypt partition would be very slow, which it is not.
TrueCrypt encryption is block-based, so only blocks which have been (partially) changed on the file system are changed on disk.
Deduplication does not work on the contents of the container file though.
Also, high entropy means no encryption.
If you trust Crashplan enough, just mount it and back up from the mountpoint.
If not, this should not be very problematic. It will just have to scan the whole 10 GiB everytime it is changed.